# How does a browser recognize "a:visited" links?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I went through the [Firefox blog from 2010](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/) which says that `getComputedStyle()` will lie in specifying whether a link has been visited or not. So, what are the alternatives being used by the browser nowadays to style "a:visited" links?

Comment: You've always been able to use a limited number of CSS properties to style a:visited elements. What's the problem?

Comment: You mean what the browser does behind the scenes? Well, fortunately it doesn't have to rely on the result of JavaScript calls; it will simply look at the browser history and display visited links in the visited color, while "officially" assigning the unvisited color to them.

Comment: @MrLister Please correct me if I'm wrong in my understanding. So for every page I visit on the browser, the browser checks for all the links in that page, then queries the browser history for each of those links and if the link is found in the history, applies the CSS style to it. Am I correct? Also, what did you mean by *"officially" assigning the unvisited color to them*?

Comment: Exactly! And by "officially" I mean that it reports all links as unvisited to whatever Javascript can throw at it. So JavaScript doesn't know better than that all links are unvisited.